# $f(y)- f(x)= (y- x)f'(x) + \frac12(y- x)^2 f''(x) + \int_x^y(y- u)(f''(u)-f''(x)) du$

Tags: analysis

I saw a Taylor expansion formula that states $f(y)- f(x)= (y- x)f'(x) + \frac12(y- x)^2 f''(x) + \underbrace{\int_x^y(y- u)(f''(u)-f''(x)) du}_{\text{remainder}}$ for every $f\in C^3$. However, I thought the remainder term was of the form $\frac12\int_x^y f'''(u)(u-y)^2du$ which comes from integration by part. Somehow I cannot understand the remainder formula $\int_x^y(y- u)(f''(u)-f''(x)) du$.

Comment: This formula is supposed to hold for any function $f$? In sake of clarity you should write carefully your hypothesis.

Comment: Your form of the remainder requires the existence of $f'''$. But as you know about integration by parts have you actually tried to evaluate that integral?

Comment: A factor $1/2$ is missing in $\int_x^y f'''(u)(u-y)^2du$. As mentioned above, integration by parts give the other representation of the remainder.

Comment: Oh, I see, by $\int_x^y(y- u)(f''(u)-f''(x)) du=\int_x^y \left[\frac{(y-u)^2}{2}\right]'(f''(u)-f''(x)) du=\int_x^y f'''(u)\frac{(u-y)^2}{2}du$.